# How to put the label above the border and not over in a TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to put the label text of an TextFormField above the border and not over it. How can I archive that?

I already tryed to use the floatingLabelBehavior, but this puts the label over the border.

```
TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(floatingLabelBehavior:FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396967/how-to-add-an-extra-label-within-textformfield

Comment: is not that effect, if you see in detail that solution, don't move the label text or the suffix either above the border of the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with the `FormField` widget which allows you to use a builder and basically make anything you want as a FormField.

However, you have to use the `state` variable from the builder to validate the text and stuff.

```
FormField(
              builder: (FormFieldState<dynamic> state) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    Text('your label'),
                    TextField(),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
```

Hope it helps. This is a very powerfull trick in my opinion since you can make anything you want. Even show the error of the field 500px lower if you want. Just gotta use the `state` variable.